# Why do I have mismatched versions of .net core sdk in one solution

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have a single solution and when I try to consolidate the Microsoft.NETCore.App, it shows a mismatched set of versions and says that I have to update the SDK to the package.  What do I need to do to resolve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer jmesolomon.  I found the issue was that I had 2 references to the Microsoft.NETCore.App in the project's .csproj file.  I removed the second one which includes the version reference and now all the projects are using 2.2.0

removed:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager` to update that. The screenshot you provided looks like you've got the Nuget Package Manager already opened.

So are you going to go with version `2.2.1`, `2.2.0` or the latest (2.2.3)?

I would probably just downgrade the project with the version `2.2.1` to `2.2.0` so you can build the solution right-away

To do so, un-tick all other projects except for the top one and you can choose to install the `2.2.0` version from the drop down.

Comment: Even when I  un-tick all but the top project, I'm still blocked by the message that I have to update the sdk to which it belongs.